# How to read a phrase from a url and what kind of stream does SWI-Prolog's `open_http/2` supply?

Tags: http, parsing, prolog, swi-prolog, dcg

I am using the SWI-Prolog `library(http/http_open)`. According to [the docs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=httpopen), "After [`http_open(Url, Stream, [])`] succeeds the data can be read from Stream." Thus, I thought maybe I could rig up a simple, declarative predicate to parse phrases from URL's by using `phrase_from_stream/2` in `library(pure_input)`:

```
phrase_from_url(Url, Phrase) :-
    http_open(Url, In, []),
    phrase_from_stream(Phrase, In),
    close(In).
```

But I suspect there is some nuance to the kinds of stream provided by `http_open/3`; I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: set_stream_position/2: stream `<stream>(0x7feebbf5c810)' does not exist (Device not configured)
```

(I have tested the same url against the example provided on the `library(http/http_open)` docs, which uses `copy_stream_data/2` to pipe the output to `user_output`, and it works. So I know the url is not at fault.)

I have learned that I can download the data from the url into a string, code-list, or text file, and then use a `phrase/n`, our cousin, on that. But I'm hoping someone can help inform me about...

1. ...an elegant/standard solution to parsing data from a url with DCGs
2. ...maybe some insight into why we cannot use `phrase_from_stream/2` on some streams, as one might naively hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is at the moment, `library(pure_input)` *does not* support non-repositioning streams. This is the problem.

One solution is to read everything and then use the normal `phrase` on it. This of course is not the same as the promised "lazy reading".

As for "parsing data from URL", keep in mind that SWI-Prolog has libraries for many things you find on the web: [SGML/XML/HTML](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%28%27packages/sgml.html%27%29); [JSON](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=jsonsupport); [RDF](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%28%27packages/rdf2pl.html%27%29).

For picking out text from an html page, see for example [this simple scraper](https://github.com/StanfordOSAcademySWIProlog/contentteam/blob/master/scrape.pl). The relevant code is in `scrape/3` and its help predicates. It uses the SWI-Prolog SGML/XML parser and [`library(xpath)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=xpath).

In the mean time, if you want to use a DCG to parse from a non-repositioning stream, tough luck. `library(pure_input)` does not even work on the standard input. What you can do, depending on how your data is structured, is either use [`read_line_to_codes/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_line_to_codes/3) (see the example), if your input is organized line-wise, or [`read_pending_input/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_pending_input/3) if it is not, and read to a buffer.

Comment: Perfect! So it turns out to be a quirk related to the magic enabling library(pure_input). Now that I know the term to search for, I see Jan has "Support non-repositioning streams, such as sockets and pipes." on the tbd. Many thanks!

Comment: @aBathologist the tdb has been there for a while. My only hope is that someone else but Jan or Ulrich Neumerkel needs it badly enough to actually do the work.

Comment: @aBathologist If you are scraping <p>s and such, parsing the html followed by xpath does the job quite well. See for example here: https://github.com/StanfordOSAcademySWIProlog/contentteam/blob/master/scrape.pl The relevant code is in `scrape/3` and its help predicates.

Answer (score 1):

As Boris pointed out, non repositioning streams cannot be used with library(pure_input). read_stream_to_codes/2, followed by phrase/2, will give you a practical way to *test* your grammar against real data.

But, 'real world' HTML is *very* difficult to parse (even with the support of the builtin SGML parser), because of the poor error handling. So debugging a DCG can be a nightmare, even on well behaved grammars.

Comment: I assumed that he must be parsing something else. But you are right with regards to "real world" html: the struggle is real.

Comment: Thanks, CapelliC. @Boris is correct, that I am only grabbing text from urls at the moment (at the worst, scraping out the contents of `<p>`s and such.  But this is good to know about 'real world' HTML handling. The poor error handling you speak of is apparently on SWI's part? So it would be better, I guess, to parse html in some other language, and then pass it back to my prolog once processed... Something to keep in mind. Thanks!

Comment: @aBathologist The way I understood CapelliC's answer, real world HTML is very difficult to parse because of the way it is usually used (structure _and_ formatting). Even using a proper, well-tested parser is difficult; if you try writing your own grammer, you are really going to have problems (this is compounded by the fact that DCGs are a bit difficult to debug...)

Comment: @aBathologist: at least, while debugging a DCG, I'd like to have codes lists displayed in readable format, to visualize the 'cursor'. I tried portray_text, set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes), and others, without luck...